# Correct way to forward declare structs?

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration

Let's suppose I want to declare structs `A` and `B`

```cpp
struct A{
  B toB(){
    return B();
  }
};
struct B{
  A toA(){
    return A();
  }
};
```

I'll get an error that type `B` is undefined

```
main.cpp:2:2: error: unknown type name 'B'
```

What is the correct way to forward-declare `B`?

Doing the following

```cpp
struct B;

struct A{
  B toB(){
    return B();
  }
};
struct B{
  A toA(){
    return A();
  }
};
```

results in

```
main.cpp:4:4: error: incomplete result type 'B' in function definition
main.cpp:1:8: note: forward declaration of 'B'
main.cpp:5:10: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'B'
main.cpp:1:8: note: forward declaration of 'B'
```

Comment: This forward declaration is fine, this has nothing to do with forward declarations. Unlike Java or C#, in C++ one does not have to define class constructors and class methods inline. The definition of the actual constructor can be moved to after both classes are defined, resolving the issue with the incomplete type.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625801/4342498) on the dupe target shows how to split this up into pieces that can be stitched together when compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't with the forward declaration, the issue is that you're trying to use a `B` before its definition. A forward declaration only tells the compiler that there is, in your case, a struct named `B`, it doesn't define it.

You can separate the definition of the method from the class, like so:

```
struct B;

struct A{
  B toB(); // B is not defined yet
};

struct B{
  A toA(){
    return A();
  }
};


B A::toB() { // Now that B is defined, you can use it
    return B();
}
```